# What argument to pass in ContextQueries for Completion Suggester in Elasticsearch for Go?

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I am trying to add a context for my completion suggester in elasticsearch for Go. I am using Olivere's elasticsearch library for Go but I am unable to determine the argument that has to be passed to ***ContextQueries()***. I can see it requires a type ***SuggesterContextQuery*** but I am unsure of how to make one.

I tried going through the [docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/olivere/elastic#CompletionSuggester) but it is still unclear to me.

```golang
func (q *CompletionSuggester) ContextQueries(queries ...SuggesterContextQuery) *CompletionSuggester {
    q.contextQueries = append(q.contextQueries, queries...)
    return q
}
```

```
type SuggesterContextQuery interface {
    Source() (interface{}, error)
}
```

Here's my code

```
sugg := "sticker-suggest"
tagSuggester := elastic.NewCompletionSuggester(sugg).Fuzziness(0).Text(term).Field("tags").SkipDuplicates(true)

searchSource := elastic.NewSearchSource().
    Suggester(tagSuggester).
    FetchSource(false).
    TrackScores(true)

searchResult, err := client.Search().
    Index(index).
    Type(Type).
    SearchSource(searchSource).
    Do(ctx)
```

How can I add a context for my completion suggester?

Comment: there is an example in the tests https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/36c8ae535866bc295bfbb74de8ddd36fd91984be/suggester_completion_test.go#L90-L96. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked this section. It was exactly what I was looking for!